# Model binding in MVC 4 with VB.NET does not work for models that use auto-implemented properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, .net-4.5

It appears that MVC 4's model binder does not work with models with VB.NET auto-implemented properties.

For example, take this contrived example where I post a simple model from JavaScript to a controller that deserializes (by way of the model binder) the input and returns it as re-serialized JSON.

ViewModel in VB.NET with auto-implemented properties:

```
Public Class CarViewModel
     Property Year As Integer
     Property Make As String
     Property Model As String
End Class
```

Controller:

```
Public Class CarController
    Inherits Controller

    <HttpPost> _
    Function Save(ByVal model as CarViewModel) As JsonResult
         Return Json(model)
    End Function

End Class
```

Client-side JS:

```
function postData() {
    var json = '{ "Year": 2000, "Make" : "Ford", "Model" : "Mustang" }';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/car/save',
        data: json,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }).done(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).error(function (e) { 
        console.log(e);
    });
}
```

This does not work as expected. From JavaScript, when I post to the MVC URL, I expect to see

```
{ "Year": 2000, "Make" : "Ford", "Model" : "Mustang" }
```

But I instead see

```
{ "Year": 0, "Make" : "", "Model" : "" }
```

If I change the CarViewModel to use standard properties:

```
Public Class CarViewModel
     Private _year as Integer
     Public Property Year As Integer
         Get
              Return _year
         End Get
         Set(ByVal value as Integer)
              _year = value
         End Set
     End Property

     ' endless typing for other properties

End Class
```

The MVC model binder works correctly, as expected.

Is it possible to use VB.NET's auto-implemented properties with MVC's model binder? Am I missing something?

Comment: Make the properties public `Public Property Model As String`

Comment: Unbelievable. Thanks!